# Ruby connect to REST service

Tags: ruby, json, http

I need to access a REST JSon Service. It's just connecting to an HTTPS using Basic authentication and performing some GETs and POSTs. This is a Ruby script running from a crontab.

These are the requirements:

- Ruby 1.8.7
- As light as possible (I'm not willing to install Rails).

Should I use HTTParty? I tried to install the gem and use it from irb with no luck. Apparently it has some dependencies.
Should I go for other library like net/http?

If HTTParty is the way to go, can you please include some instructions on how to get it to work in an IRB console?

Comment: For HTTParty examples check out the examples directory on [Github](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/tree/master/examples).

Comment: The dependencies are multi_json and multi_xml. You'll need a json parser if you roll your own anyway.

Comment: Regarding your "no luck" install: What OS, Ruby version? What error message? I just installed httparty successfully on Windows/1.9.3 and Ubuntu/RVM/1.9.3 and JRuby 1.6.7

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu/Ruby 1.8.7, maybe there's a problem with that. Even though the gem is installed, I get this error: `require': no such file to load -- httparty (LoadError)

Comment: with 1.8 you'll need to `require 'rubygems'` first.

Comment: Edd, thanks for that! That solved my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I am connecting to a REST/JSON/API or just a site directly I go for [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) / [Merhanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) / [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) depending on what exactly I need to do with the site. I also would be sure to check [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients) in their HTTPClient category for other popular gems.

```
>> require "httparty"
=> true
>> response = HTTParty.get("http://justinherrick.com/posts/what-it-means-to-stay-dry.json")
=> #<HTTParty::Response:0x104ceac70 @parsed_response={"slug"=>"what-it-means-to-stay-dry", "pubdate"=>"2012-02-06", "created_at"=>"2012-02-06T22:08:05+00:00", "category"=>"Programming", "title"=>"What it means to stay DRY", "body"=>"A very common and useful programming idiom...
```

Answer (score 1):

[ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) might do the trick in a more elegant way than HTTParty.

Comment: I've read something about it and looked really interesting. But I'm wondering if it's not overkilling in this case as I need just a ruby script to make some simple requests.